# Reference Request: simple graph vertex labelings with balanced induced edge weights

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

Say that the edge weight induced by a vertex labeling is the sum of the weights of the two vertices comprising it. Here is the problem of interest: given a simple $d$-regular graph $G = (V,E)$, find a (bijective) vertex labeling $\ell: V \to \{1, \dots, |V|\}$ which minimizes the difference-sum; that is, the difference between the weight of the highest-weighted edge and the weight of the lowest-weighted edge. That is:

> difference-sum$(\ell)$ = max-sum$(\ell)$ $-$ min-sum$(\ell)$, where
>
> max-sum$(\ell) = \max_{\{v_i,v_j\} \in E} \{\ell(v_i) + \ell(v_j) \}$
>
> min-sum$(\ell) = \min_{\{v_i,v_j\} \in E} \{\ell(v_i) + \ell(v_j) \}$

I have been unable to find any literature which addresses this problem, so I am hoping that someone can point me to some papers that address this matter.